# How do I delete thousands of unattached images?

Tags: images, attachments, customization

I have thousands of unattached images with no files. How do I delete them all quickly?

> ls: cannot access wp-content/uploads/2014/09/jeep cherokee patriot-Ekza.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: I ended up using SQL and shell commands to remove them all. I selected all the unattached attachments into a file, used a `for` loop to list then remove the file, then deleted the rows from the database. I wish I saved the SQL and command line.

Comment: Could you please share the code you used? I am about to do the same thing. If you still have access to that database command line, then it would be in the history.

Comment: I want to have this code as well, can you please share it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the wp-cli command-line, see eg answers here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/262823/26350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a lot of unattached images.
If you have couple of hundred images then you can delete them manually from media library.

```
1. Click 'Screen Options' at the top right and set 'Show on screen' to 200.
2. Click 'Apply'.
3. Click the checkbox just under 'Bulk Actions' to check all images on the page.
4. Select 'Delete Permanently' in the 'Bulk Actions' dropdown.
5. Click 'Apply'.
```

But if you have thousand of unattached images then it would be best to use a plugin.
[DNUI (Delete not used image)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dnui-delete-not-used-image-wordpress/) plugin will do that for you. It will let you delete tons of images from media library.

Or use [DX Delete Attached Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dx-delete-attached-media/)

Comment: My dashboard looks [like this](https://imgur.com/SKysGLs), I don't see any screen options.

Comment: @Suncatcher I had the same issue. You need to change to "list"-view beforehand. Then you have the screen options. It's much easier to delete the files like this

Comment: `DNUI (Delete not used image) plugin`: This plugin has been closed as of January 10, 2023 and is not available for download. Reason: Security Issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools/plugins now in the repository.

You can check out these two:

https://mediahygiene.com/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/

Out of these two, I find the first one to be more thorough and has more capability. The second one is good, but you need to pay for a pro license to get the same features.